# abrtd: Node Process was killed by signal 6 (SIGABRT)

Tags: linux, node.js, kill, sigabrt, sigterm

I am running a Node program that does a long running data migration job. After an hour is process, Node process terminates by Abrt daemon and creates core dump.

Looking into the reason I see this:

`node process was killed by signal 6 (SIGABRT)`

Any ideas why Node process is killed and how to deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be MemoryLeak issue in Strong-Oracle module I am using. I have increased Nodejs process memory to run with 4G memory. Working fine now.